# How to resolve hostname with ipv6 address?

Tags: java

It is easy to resolve hostname with ipv4 address, but I am not able to  resolve hostname with ipv6 address even using Inet6Address class.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.190.62");
String host = addr.getHostName();
System.out.println(host);
```

Above code works for IPv4, but for IPv6 even with Inet6Address it is not working.

Please help, how is it possible ?

Comment: It doesn't depend on your code but on your OS's name resolution system; if it can't do then your code can't do

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Short of using a DNS library, no... And anyway, how do you query these addresses? You don't show a code for querying IPv6

Comment: Same as above but I am using Inet6Address for IPv6. And I will provide full IPv6 address.